# list elements as indices

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I have the list `R`:

```
R={{-π, -π}, {-π, -(π/2)}, {-π, 0}, {-π, π/2}, 
{-(π/2), -π}, {-(π/2), -(π/2)}, {-(π/2), 0}, {-(π/2), π/2}, 
{0, -π}, {0, -(π/2)}, {0, 0}, {0, π/2}, 
{π/2, -π}, {π/2, -(π/2)}, {π/2, 0}, {π/2, π/2}, 
{-π, -π}, {-π, -(π/2)}, {-π, 0}, {-π, π/2}, 
{-(π/2), -π}, {-(π/2), -(π/2)}, {-(π/2), 0}, {-(π/2),π/2}, 
{0, -π}, {0, -(π/2)}, {0, 0}, {0, π/2}, 
{π/2, -π}, {π/2, -(π/2)}, {π/2, 0}, {π/2, π/2}}
```

How can I produce the list $(1_{(-\pi,-\pi)}, 1_{(-\pi/2,-\pi/2)}, \dots, 1_{(-\pi,-\pi)}, \dots,  1_{(\pi/2,\pi/2)}) $, i.e make the elements of the list `R` indices of the elements of another list with the same `Length`?

Can I also add a superscript to the elements of the new list? E.g $(1^{a}_{(-\pi,-\pi)}, 1^{a}_{(-\pi/2,-\pi/2)}, \dots, 1^{b}_{(-\pi/2,-\pi/2)},\dots, 1^{b}_{(\pi/2,\pi/2)}) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
Subscript[1, ##] & @@@ R
```

and:

```
MapThread[
 Subsuperscript[1, Row[#1, ","], #2]&,
 {
  R,
  Join[
    ConstantArray["a", Length[R]/2], 
    ConstantArray["b", Length[R]/2]
  ]
 }
]
```

?

## Edit

If you want parentheses around the subscripts, you can use:

```
Subsuperscript[1, Row[{"(", Row[#1, ","], ")"}], #2]&
```

in the `MapThread` instead.

Comment: Can I include the subscripts in parentheses or curly brackets e.g $1_{(-\pi,-\pi)}$ or $1_{\{-\pi,-\pi\}}$?

Comment: You can use `Subsuperscript[1, #1, #2]&` in the 2nd code block instead if you want curly brackets. `Subsuperscript[1, Row[{"(", Row[#1, ","], ")"}], #2]&` gives you parentheses.